# Angular 2: [hidden] and *NgIf not working?

Tags: javascript, angular

So i have this table showing a green circle if data is available. in `gegevensAanwezig` you have a schoolname a schoolcode and some booleans(Entreetoets, Eindtoets etc) to show if data is available or not.

```
        <tr *ngFor="let g of gegegevensAanwezig">
            <td>{{ g.brinCode }}</td>
            <td>{{ g.schoolNaam }}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><div class="circle" [hidden]="!g.Entreetoets">  </div> </td>
            <td><div class="circle" [hidden]="!g.Eindtoets">  </div></td>
            <td><div class="circle" [hidden]="!g.BLez">  </div></td>
            <td><div class="circle" [hidden]="!g.BLui">  </div></td>
            <td><div class="circle" [hidden]="!g.DMT">  </div></td>
            <td><div class="circle" [hidden]="!g.ORD">  </div></td>
            <td><div class="circle" [hidden]="!g.RW">  </div></td>
            <td><div class="circle" [hidden]="!g.SP">  </div></td>
            <td><div class="circle" [hidden]="!g.SV">  </div></td>
            <td><div class="circle" [hidden]="!g.TL">  </div></td>
            <td><div class="circle" [hidden]="!g.TV">  </div></td>
            <td><div class="circle" [hidden]="!g.TVK">  </div></td>
            <td><div class="circle" [hidden]="!g.WS">  </div></td>
        </tr>
```

The `g.brinCode` & `g.schoolNaam` are working they show the schoolname and schoolcode just fine. But `[hidden]` or `*NgIf` is not working. Either all circles are shown or nothing is shown.

Is this because of `Angular-universal` rendering the view on the backend while data is being loaded after it is served by the browser?

I used `if (isBrowser)` to load data after the view is served because i needed the `localStorage`.

screenshot:[image]
The white space should be filled with some green circles based on if the boolean is true or false

`console.log(gegevensAanwezig)`:[image]

Comment: is g.Entreetoets is a boolean value ?

Comment: @ArunKumaresh https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAZ8f.png

Comment: It looks correct, did you check your css? Maybe the div with circle class has 0px width or height?

Comment: @mankers yes the css is right because when i change this  `[hidden]="!g.Entreetoets"` to this `[hidden]="!g.Entreetoets"` it just show circles in all rows in the EntreeToets column

Comment: Maybe I am too tired now, but I can't see any difference between `[hidden]="!g.Entreetoets"` and `[hidden]="!g.Entreetoets"`

Comment: @mankers i mean this `[hidden]="!g.Entreetoets"` to this `[hidden]="g.Entreetoets" ` my bad but its fixed now thanks for the help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turned out somehow angular does not recognize capital variables..
I changed everything to lowercase and it worked..

Comment: This happened to me today, your solution fixed it, idk why isn't this fixed yet. I'm using angular cli v1.5.4. This happened in the official Heroes tutorial when I was trying to use *ngIf

Answer (score 1):

just check for

```
<div *ngIf = "gegegevensAanwezig">
   //then procced with the ngFor
</div
```

updated after comment

try and add this to style sheet also check it the hidden attribute is attached to the element in the dom.

```
[hidden] {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this doesnt work. Do you know if it has something to do with `Angular-universal`? still gave u a vote up btw because of the effort

Comment: Thats the problem i dont get any error. its just either all the elements in the table row are shown or everything is hidden...

Comment: @Jessedegans its not beacuse of angular-universal i guess did you try and log these values ?

Comment: Yes i did its array of 19 all values just filled. I dont understand how this is not working btw i included a screenshot in the question to make it more 'visual' ;)

Comment: i am not talking about the brincode and schoolname try logging the boolean value

Comment: me neither check the updated answer screenshot of console log included in the question. The first image is just the view how it looks now without the green circles showing anywhere

Comment: updated the answer check it out @Jessedegans. Also please check once if the hidden attribute is getting added to the element or not in the dom

Comment: still not working :( it seems like all the divs are bind to [hidden] every div it shows `[hidden]{display:none;}` when thats the deleted its still hidden because of the following `div[Attributes Style] {
    display: none;
}` could that have something to do witht he problem?

Comment: @Jessedegans can you post a plunker for the same, i tried in my local is works flawlessly